# What directory or path open() point to if there is no path name specified

Tags: python, directory

if the the path in the open() method is just a file name, what default directory is it pointing to?

```
def write_dicts_to_file(path,data):
    with open(path,'wb') as fp:
        for d in data:
            fp.write(json.dumps(d).encode('utf-8'))
            fp.write("\n".encode('utf-8'))
write_dicts_to_file("train.json",training_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory of the python file from which you called the `write_dicts_to_file()` method.